# How do I hide Soap Faults in python suds?

Tags: python, suds

If there is a `Soap Fault` error during a transaction, the error is displayed on screen. How do I hide these errors from the user? I am catching them using an exception block, but they still appear in the output. If I have this code:

```
try:
    print "A"
    self.client.service.something()
    print "B"
except suds.WebFault as (err):
    print "C"
    self.handleError(err)
```

the output will be

```
A
ERROR:suds.client:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> [..]
C
```

I don't want to output anything between `A` and `C`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code at the start of your script:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```